# CakePHP: How to render an element in a layout?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, element

I use the following to render an element in `view/users/index.ctp`:

```
$this->renderElements('users/lmenu');
```

But when use the same line in the layout `default.ctp` I get an error:

```
Call to undefined method View::renderElements()
```

How can I display an element in a layout?

Comment: should it not be `$this->element('users/lmenu');` ? that certainly works in layouts (I assume `default.ctp` is your layout)

Comment: renderElement() is deprecated in CakePHP 1.3 and 2.0. Try $this->element() instead as Ross points out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mensch had the best hint in the comments:

> `renderElement()` is deprecated in CakePHP 1.3 and 2.0. Try `$this->element()` instead